# Android app bar action buttons off-centered

Tags: android, android-layout

I followed the tutorial for setting up the standard Android app bar, but I noticed the action buttons and menu button aren't centered in the bar. How do I fix that?

[image: appbar]

Here's the corresponding code:

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="35dp"
android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />
```

Menu items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/star_big_on"
        android:title="favorite"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="settings" />

</menu>
```

Main Activity setup:

```
// Setup toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Menu setup:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_toolbar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you share your xml code for showing appbar & toolbar?

Comment: Added code to the main post @MohamedMohaideenAH

Comment: Change your `minHeight` of toolbar to `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` in xml code.

Comment: Perfect that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready-made in the Android Studio that allows you to have the appbar and other objects to be in the right position.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I tried looking and messing around with settings but couldn't find anything that seemed to control placement of those icons.

Comment: A layout with correct appBar right? if you're creating a new layout, there should be a ready-made ayout.